# rails, alternative to .group into the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Given an `Invoice` model based on an underlying table defined by the following (piece of) migration:

```
  t.date :date
  t.string :customer_name
  t.string :payment_type
  t.decimal :amount
```

After having implemented a software that manages the invoices entry, i finally want to do some report on them.

I want to group invoices by different fields. Grouping by the date and calling(SQL) `SUM(amount) as total_amount` i will get the daily sales figure and so on.

How to implement this?

I've learned from [the official guide of active record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) that a way is something like so:

```
r = Invoice.select("date, sum(amount) as sum_amount").group(:date)
```

Well this works, but puzzles me with some questions.

Despite the fact that r is an instance of Invoice, it doesn't even have `Invoice`'s fields, as an obvious consequence of the SQL that has generated it.

So I end up with a class full of logic that references fields that don't exist, that handles persistence when these are summary data and it doesn't make sense to think of persisting them. 
And despite the fact that it could work, it doesn't seem to be a best practice.

So which could be instead a best practice to manage such situations with active record query interface?

Comment: How about using database views? http://pivotallabs.com/database-views-performance-rails/

Comment: Well, well i'm exploring this possibility; you would have new, different model with no group option that would usually be inside the view definition. But in some situations i would prefer being able to change the group by option and in this case the view would loose its major reason. Now i'm thinking of just using a different model, with summary-oriented accessors and so on, based on the very same table.

Comment: I tend to ditch models for non-model things like this and go straight to a low level `select_rows`, you can always map the array-of-arrays that gives to more objecty things with a bit of manual type wrangling and Struct wrapping if you necessary. You may notice that `r.first.sum_amount.class` would be `String` in that example so AR isn't exactly being helpful. Sometimes the official guides are dumb because of the official ideology and opinion overriding simple good sense.